# renaming and putting a note on package management , self deleting after long period of time not in use

Tags: package, nuget-package, package.json

how to automate self delete of package if not used in a year or more?

how to put message or log with date() time() ddmmyyyy hhmmss on package downloaded? trace file missing. so as to keep track on package that may need to upgrade and update in due time.

tried settings on vscode and runned.